# DC Motor: Split rings vs commutator

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

**Question**: In a simple DC motor (as shown below), explain the effect that replacing the commutator with slip rings would have on the operation of the
motor, if no other change was made?

**My Attempt**: I thought that the motor would then run as an AC motor but the answer given by my teacher is that the motor would no longer function and that the loop would rotate by one-quarter of a revolution to the vertical position but would not rotate further.

Is this indeed correct? If so, I still don't understand how this is the case. If the only thing changing is the commutator to a slip ring, does this not form an AC motor? From the diagrams I have seen, it seems like the only difference between a DC motor and an AC motor are the rings.

[image]

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related - [What would happen to a motor without a split-ring commutator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/250194/what-would-happen-to-a-motor-without-a-split-ring-commutator)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are both right! With a slip ring it becomes an AC motor, and it will not run on DC.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/278943)

Comment: @Kyle Kanos, how is this not an answer? OP is only asking for help, I point out that his thoughts are correct, as are his teacher's, and only the fact is overlooked that the AC motor won't run _in this circuit_ because the power is DC.

Comment: @Zaaikort thank you for sharing. That last line cleared it up for me very well...so the holding point is at the power supply which is a DC source - this makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

This is no different to a coil connected to a power supply without any sort of commutator being used.

All depends on the initial orientation of the plane of the coil relative to the magnetic field.

If they start at right angles to one another not a lot happens as there is no torque exerted on the coil.

If they start out parallel to one another then the coil will have a torques exerted on it and it will start to move.

The subsequent motion very much depends on the magnitude of the frictional forces acting on the system but the final position of the plane of the coil will be perpendicular to the magnetic field.

If the frictional forces are small the coil will overshoot the final "equilibrium" position and stop at a position where it has rotated less than $180^\circ$.
The coil will then rotate in the opposite direction and continue undergoing damped harmonic (backwards and forwards) motion until it stops at the final "equilibrium" position.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I now make the following conclusion based on the above response from @zaaikort. Initially, the DC supply will only provide power for the DC direction of current flow which will rotate the loop to 90deg before it then converts to AC current direction flow to which then the motor will cease (because it is being supplied with DC power at this point but it needs an AC power source)?

Comment: @Mr.curious The purpose of the split ring commutator is to reverse the direction of the current in the coil every half a revolution and so produce continuous rotary motion.  With slip rings the current direction stays the same so the coil rotates a quarter of a revolution and then, even though the toques due to interaction of the current and magnetic field opposes the motion of the coil, the coil overshoots its final position due to its inertia. The coil then stops and stars moving back towards its final position under the action of the torque produced by the interaction of current and field.